# Include Laravel into custom PHP script and routing to a controller

Tags: php, url, laravel, laravel-4, routes

Let's say there's a web-based PHP project which uses an independent framework and also contains a folder with [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2):

```
project/
    laravel/ (Laravel install)
        app/
            routes.php
        public/
            index.php
    index.php
    test.php
    .htaccess
```

The *.htaccess* file rewrites every query to the independent framework's *index.php*, unless a PHP script is requested (e.g., *project/test.php*).

In this case, *test.php* contains `require laravel/public/index.php` to include Laravel's *index.php* script. The URI to access this is `http://example.com/test.php`.

How can I make use of [Laravel's routing](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) to pick up on this script? I've tried this:

```
Route::get('/test.php', function()
{
    echo 'success';exit;
});
```

But that doesn't work (I've tried *test.php* and just *test*). Dumping `Route::getCurrentRoute()` outputs this:

> ```
> object(Illuminate\Routing\Route)[126]
>   protected 'uri' => string '/' (length=1)
>   ...
>   protected 'compiled' => 
>     object(Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute)[135]
>       ...
>       private 'staticPrefix' => string '/' (length=1)
>       ...
> ```

Is it possible to access `http://example.com/test.php` and have Laravel's Routing see it as if `/test` or `/test.php` has been requested, without making changes to the independent framework's *.htaccess* file?

Comment: I don't understand what you _need_. Would you like to serve the /test.php URL through Laravel even though it's a physical .php file on the server? That won't work. Laravel's rewrite rules explicitly make physical files take precedence over internal routing. Do it the other way around: move it in a non-public path and then set it up as a normal Laravel route and _require_ resources from the external application.

Comment: Well, basically, I want to use the script _test.php_ as an entry point to a controller. I'd like to write a route in Laravel to connect the route _/test.php_ to a controller.

Comment: Why do you wanna do that? What are you doing inside text.php?

Comment: Because I want to learn if it's possible to use Laravel's routing system can be manipulated to work that way without touching its source. Essentially I don't have to do anything inside of _test.php_, just including Laravel's _index.php_.

Comment: You can implement your custom routing classes: https://github.com/pixeloution/laravel-custom-router

Comment: It *might* be possible to simply define a route that matches "/[a-z0-9]\.php" (or something like that) and execute an arbitrary PHP file, but that seems like **a very bad idea** for security reasons. You could whitelist some files, I guess, but the question "why?" comes to mind. If it's a completely independent application, why not divorce if from Laravel entirely, put it in it's own folder with a virtual host definition, and redirect to it from Laravel if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not forced to use Laravel routing, you can bypass it with pure PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/test.php')
{
    exit('success');
}
```

But in your case, you probably should redirect all requests to Laravel with the .htaccess and fall back to root index.php when Laravel does not handle the page:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    include('../../index.php');
    exit;
});
```